# Aquaris M10 GPS unavailable to apps

Tags: gps, m10

Just to get this out of the way, the problem is not in the system settings; everything is set correctly so that the apps all have access to location data. I installed the Location Test app, and it does, in fact, give the correct coordinates for my location. However, the Nearby and Weather scopes do not access that information, and instead default to a location that it stored during shipping (at the UPS warehouse). Meanwhile, uNav shows a location in London, or, sometimes, my correct location, which is in New England in the US.

EDIT: Also, the Here navigation is turned on and Nokia terms accepted.

Comment: You need to look over what you wrote and do a little editing. You are supposed to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug report filed for this problem here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/location-service/+bug/1573168

It worked for me before running update on my M10. After the updates the location icon started blinking. I eventually fixed it simply by turning off the WIFI and GPS location services, turning off WIFI and GPS in the power settings and rebooting the phablet (press and hold down power button for option). I'm not sure how to tell if I get lock-on to satalites but at least the phablet knows where I am now.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that, and at first thought it worked. However, the weather scope now has the correct location, Nearby now puts me elsewhere in the same state, and uNav still thinks I'm in London.

Comment: Perhaps GPS is not working because of the mentioned bug but location is guessing what it can from WIFI, which can often be quite wrong.